# Android Studio Error:resource style/Base.V26.Theme.AppCompat (aka de.webducer.androidbuch.zeiterfassung:style/Base.V26.Theme.AppCompat) not found

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-studio-3.0

I started a new Project in Android Studio 3.0.1 and got following error Messages

[image]